# Accessing ListBox selected item via UiApp.getActiveApplication().getElementByID()

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently I am using UiService to create a form and I uses ListBox, from what I understand to pass a value via handler will be something like *e.parameter.[Name of ListBox]* to access the selected item.

Does anyone know is it possible to use like *app.getElementById([Name of ListBox])* to access the selected item. The reason I am using this method is because my list of ListBox-es are dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time looking for this answer as well, but finally I tried one idea and it worked.

You can use `e.parameter` as an array so you can these two will give the same:

```
e.parameter.LIST_BOX_NAME
```

and

```
e.parameter['LIST_BOX_NAME']
```

So in the second sample any dynamic list box ID can be used. I use same handler for all added dropdown list and have this code to check what dropdown was changed and what value it has now:

```
  if (e.parameter[e.parameter.source] == 'a'){
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the content of the listBox you can use  `app.getElementById('ID of the listBox')`, from there you can  `clear()` and `addItems` again but you cannot read the listItems.
When I need to do this I usually store the list of items somewhere else, in a place that I can read anytime, for example the list of items can be stored as a string in the listBox tag itself so I have all items at hand to repopulate the listBox after I have clear it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I wish to actually get the value of the current selected item in the ListBox instead of the whole list of items in the ListBox.

Comment: ...then e.parameter.Name is the only way I'm afraid :-) The whole list is only useful if you need to modify it 'on the fly' in a handler function (since you said they were dynamic)